Does tapping already tapped creature counts as "committing a crime"?
The Sterling Keykeeper is on the table and a player activates its ability (2, Tap: Tap target non-Mount creature), targeting opponent's tapped non-Mount creature. Does "commit a crime" triggers in this case?
My instinct says that the answer is "Yes", but I can't find the proof in the comp. rules.

Yes, you committed a crime.
For a crime to have occurred, all that matters is that you targeted something.

700.13. Some cards refer to committing a crime. A player commits a crime as that player casts a spell, activates an ability, or puts a triggered ability on the stack and that spell or ability targets at least one opponent; at least one permanent, spell, or ability an opponent controls; and/or at least one card in an opponent’s graveyard.

If you target a tapped creature with Sterling Keykeeper, the effect resolves but doesn't do anything, because you can't tap an already tapped creature.
The rules for "crime", however, don't require that the spell or ability has to actually do anything, or even resolve. Successfully targeting something is all that is required.
